# How to fix this error? Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-navigationview

[image]

**LOGCAT**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.batyaa.first_gear_automotive, PID: 2582
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.batyaa.first_gear_automotive/com.example.batyaa.first_gear_automotive.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.batyaa.first_gear_automotive.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.example.batyaa.first_gear_automotive.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:23) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.example.batyaa.first_gear_automotive.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:23) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:207)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:281)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:193)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:104)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.example.batyaa.first_gear_automotive.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:23) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:207) 
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:281) 
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:193) 
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:104) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.example.batyaa.first_gear_automotive.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:23) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.batyaa.first_gear_automotive:drawable/logo" (7f070103) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f070103 a=-1 r=0x7f070103}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Re
Application terminated.
```

**HOME ACTIVITY**
 private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);



    //SECOND MENU

    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.navigation_drawer_close, R.string.navigation_drawer_open);
    mToggle.syncState();

   // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //*******************************  SETTING UP SCROLL BAR *********************************



}

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
    {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    else
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //EXTRA SETTINGS MENU DROP DOWN
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.nav_drawer , menu );
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == R.id.action_settings)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
    {
        return  true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

    int id =  menuItem.getItemId();

    if(id == R.id.inventory)
    {
        Intent  goToInventory = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, InventoryActivity.class);
        startActivity(goToInventory);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Welcome To Car Inventory", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(id == R.id.home)
    {
        Intent  goToLocation = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(goToLocation);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Welcome To HOME", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(id == R.id.location)
    {
        Intent  goToLocation = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, LocationActivity.class);
        startActivity(goToLocation);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Welcome To Store Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(id == R.id.office_hours)
    {
        Intent  goToOfficeHours = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Office_Hours_Activity.class);
        startActivity(goToOfficeHours);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Welcome To Our Office Hours", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(id == R.id.warranty)
    {
        Intent  goToWarranty = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Warranty_Activity.class);
        startActivity(goToWarranty);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Welcome To Our Car Warranty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if  (id == R.id.feedback)
    {
        Intent  goToFeedback = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Feedback_Activity.class);
        startActivity(goToFeedback);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Welcome To Car Feedback", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.batyaa.first_gear_automotive:drawable/logo" (7f070103) is not a Drawable (color or path)`. There is some issue with your `logo` drawable.

Comment: I dont understand what does that have to do with logo/ It says something about navigation and inflater. I changed the logo and still same error

Comment: Can you include the layout you're using as the header of your `NavigationView`?

Comment: You also declared the `DrawerLayout` twice-three times!! Just add it above of `onCreate` then declare it inside `onCreate` method and then you'll be able to use it all over the `Activity`. However, ian answered the main issue. The reason why you're getting such error `NotFoundException: Resource ID` is because it tries to find that resource which couldn't be found. Perhaps adding `CarsAdapter.onBindViewHolder` to your question can help us?

Answer (score 3):

The error message includes

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
    Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class ImageView at 
 ...
android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(
    NavigationMenuPresenter.java:207)
...
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:
    Resource "com.example.batyaa.first_gear_automotive:drawable/logo" (7f070103
    is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f070103 a=-1 r=0x7f070103}
```

Your `@drawable/logo` included in the layout you've set as the header of your `NavigationView` is not a valid drawable.

Comment: Removing the logo worked ! Thank you, but now i am getting a new error when opening one activity from menu

Comment: 09-30 19:08:00.801 3287-3287/com.example.batyaa.first_gear_automotive E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.batyaa.first_gear_automotive, PID: 3287
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0700a2
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:804)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:771)
        at com.example.batyaa.first_gear_automotive.CarsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CarsAdapter.java:61)

Comment: Since your original problem is solved, I'd strongly suggest you mark this as the answer and post a new question, making sure that your new question includes the `CarsAdapter`'s `onBindViewHolder` line 61 that is mentioned in your new error.

Comment: Okay so here is the issue. ONLY if i remove the draawble from nav_header the app runs and one activity crashes. But even then i cannot replace the header image. So replacing the header images gives the same error even making a new layout

Comment: You'll need to edit your question and add the layout you've set as your header and what type of image you're using (i.e., I put a png named image.png in the `drawable` folder) for me to help you with why your header image is invalid.

Comment: i add a screenshot would not allow me to add layout code

Comment: So what about your logo?